# Executing JavaScript when a div content is changed (or t he div is resized)

Tags: javascript, html, css-position

This will be a long post, sorry for that, I'd just like to explain what I'm trying to do and why, and what I've tried so far.

I was asked to put a banner (legal disclaimer) on top of a page that stays on top no matter how the page is scrolled. After going down the rabbit hole of trying to make a `<div>` with `position: sticky` work, I gave up and went with `position: fixed`.

(Long story short, there's too much going on the page in terms of css styles that I don't have control over/don't have the resources to investigate and fix, that's causing the `sticky` to not work and the `<div>` to scroll with the rest of the page.)

`position: fixed` made the `<div>` stick to the top of the page, but it caused another problem: The div now overlaps the top of the scrollable page content. In other words, even when scrolled all the way to the top, a bit of the content is covered by the `div`. Important content. The top menu bar.

To get around this I put another empty div on the top of the page just to take up space. I effectively made the scrollable content of the page a bit taller. This works fine, as long as the user doesn't resize the window. If they do that, the disclaimer div changes height, but the padding div doesn't. So I turned to JavaScript:

```
 $(window).on('resize', function () {
    $("#disclaimer-padding").height($("#disclaimer-container").height());
 });
```

I realize I'm well into the workaround/clumsy hack territory, but what was I supposed to do? The damn sticky thing wouldn't work. Anyway, this works, except for one last usecase:

If the user loads the page while not in fullscreen, or they have a smaller screen, or a device in portrait mode, the padding div height won't match the height of the disclaimer when the page loads.

I naturally tried putting the same code in `$(window).on('load')` or `$(document).on('ready')`. But the problem is that the content of the disclaimer, like many other elements on the page, is loaded by AngularJS (which grabs it from backend, which grabs it from the database or server-side cache) and both `window.load` and `document.ready` fire long before Angular is done loading and the final height of the div is known.

My next thought was "I'll listen for the context of the div to change, and trigger the resize then". So I used a MutationObserver.

```
const targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
let observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
function callback() {
  $("#disclaimer-padding").height($("#disclaimer-container").height());
}
observer.observe(targetNode , config);
```

I tried hooking this up in window.load and in document.ready. It didn't work, which really surprised me, because when I tried it in a minimal working test page, it worked like a charm. But alas, in my project, the callback function just never got called. I have no idea why.

In the end I implemented a truly ugly solution (which I found somewhere here on StackOverflow). In window.load I call a function that periodically checks the contents of my diclaimer div. If the content has changed (until it's loaded it says something like #Application.DislaimerContent) then it will set the height, otherwise it will schedule itself to run again in 200 miliseconds using `setTimeout()`.

I don't like this solution, but I was running out of time and this is the only thing that worked. But I feel like if my supervisor ever sees this, he'll give me an earful and make me fix it.

So the question is, how do I fix it? How do I make the code register when the div has loaded, and resize the other div accordingly?

Comment: Instead of putting an empty div to take up space, how about putting an exact copy of the banner? So no matter what users do, the padding div and the banner will resize in the same way.

Comment: That's exactly what I did in the end :D